# How to underline text in Visual Basic (with Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba

I have a problem with underline text after press a button in Visual Basic. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I red in tutorial that in button method I have to use for example:

```
lbltext.FontUnderline = True
```

But I don't have variable "FontUnderline". Of course I was trying to find other variable or function to do this but without success. Anyone know how to do this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

An inline answer looks like this:

```
Me.lbltext.Font =  New Font(lbltext.Font, FontStyle.Underline)
```

This would save multiple lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

Or the old way of doing it was to instance a new font

```
Font standardFont = new Font(lblText.Font)
Font underFont = new Font(standardFont,FontStyle.Underline)
```

Then just set the Font property of the relevant controls to the one you want.

Answer (score 3):

Took the example of @Tony Hopkinson and added some small changes to make this work for VB.NET

So this is the syntax for VB.NET

```
Dim standardFont As Font = lblExportDate.Font
Dim underFont As New Font(standardFont, FontStyle.Underline)

Me.lblExportDate.Font = underFont
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a dot here.

It should be `lbltext.Font.Underline = true`

Comment: But in this way variable Underline is read only so I can't change it.